# Stripping unwanted/excess data from shapefile using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, arcgis-10.0, attribute-joins

I have a dataset that contains a unique identifier, and a .dbf file that I need to join to my shapefile. This is the only field that I can do a join on.

The .dbf field is a 8-digit unique number, but the matching field in my shapefile has extra data both in front of and behind a number of rows. When I run the join, it understandably comes up blank as none of the rows match exactly.

If the problem was reversed, I would just strip the extra data from the .dbf file.

Is there a way I can do that in ArcMap 10.0?

Comment: Please provide an example of the values you are trying to join.

Answer (score 3):

Try trimming the leading/ending numbers off and then do a join.

Since you can't edit the FId (I don't think so) make a new field and copy that data to it so you can then edit.

Comment: well, i can edit the field if i want to. it's a rather large dataset though, so i wanted to trim the numbers off in a batch edit of some kind.

Comment: I FIGURED IT OUT. really simple actually. did a find and replace. took me a bit to come to this conclusion on my own!